# error: no match for call to ‘(std::fstream {aka std::basic_fstream<char>}) (const char*)’ Not fixed by c_str()

Tags: c++, file, compiler-errors

I have an assignment for my operating systems class which is supposed to warm us up to C++ (our department doesn't teach it at the introductory level). And in the project we have to do file reading. I tried to create a class called `FileIO` which would handle most of the file reading, it would just need the file name passed onto it. However when I try to initialize it like `knightFile(knightFileName.c_str())`, the compiler gives me the error in the title. Anyone know what's going on?

Most I've tried is converting the filename to a c-string with `c_str`. However I still get the same error.

```
FileIO::FileIO()
{
    knightFile (knightFileName.c_str());
    castleFile (castleFileName.c_str());
    knightFileName = "Knight";
    castleFileName = "Castle";
}

//All of the above variables are declared in the header file. knightFile 
//and castleFile are fstreams and knightFileName and castleFileName are 
//strings.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first assign your `string` members, and then you can pass them to the `fstream::open()` method:

```cpp
FileIO::FileIO()
{
    knightFileName = "Knight";
    castleFileName = "Castle";

    knightFile.open(knightFileName.c_str());
    castleFile.open(castleFileName.c_str());
}
```

Otherwise, get rid of the `string` members, and call the `fstream` constructors in your constructor's *member initialization list*:

```cpp
FileIO::FileIO() :
    knightFile ("Knight"),
    castleFile ("Castle")
{
}
```

Comment: I think that fixed it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list), otherwise `knightFile` and `castleFile` will be implicitly constructed before the body of the constructor is executed.

Then it's like you are trying to call the constructor on an already constructed object

```
Foo foo();
foo(); // does not work unless operator() is implemented which is not what you want
```

So instead use initializer lists:

```
FileIO::FileIO()
  : knightFile("Knight"), castleFile("Castle")
{    }
```

Setting the file names **after** you have used them to open the file is probably not what you want as well.

If you need the filename variables, you could use `std::fstream::open()` as  in [Remy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57964783/4253931) or a default member initializer in the header:

```
// .hpp
class FileIO {
    FileIO();
    std::string knightFileName{"Knight"};
    std::string castleFileName{"Castle"};
    std::fstream knightFile;
    std::fstream castleFile;
};
// .cpp
FileIO::FileIO()
  : knightFile(knightFileName), castelFile(castleFileName)
{  }
```

Comment: Be careful with this approach. If `knightFile` and `castleFile` are declared before `knightFileName` and `castleFileName` in the `FileIO` class, the `fstream`s will be initialized before the `string`s are initialized.  A "member initialization list" merely provides input values to each member's constructor, it DOES NOT control the order of initialization, like one would expect. The order of declarations does that instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Would that even compile? I think initializer lists have to be in the order of declaration.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Oh, then it is only a compiler warning. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: There is no guarantee that a compiler warning will be issued if the initialization list is in a different order than the declarations.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, i know. That's why I said, I will edit the answer. Warnings always depend on compilers and active flags.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ok, did not expect that one. I thought default initializers would have an effect on initialization order. I guess I should read more about object lifetime.

Comment: See [Constructors and member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) particularly the section on "Initialization order"

Answer (score 0):

At that point in the constructor you are trying to call the nonexistent () method on the fstream objects vs their constructor.

Please try

```
FileIO::FileIO():
    knightFile("Knight"),
    castleFile("Castle")
{
}
```